# No write-access to samba share

Tags: samba

I have two notebooks (Notebook 1 with Ubuntu 10.04 and Notebook 2 with Ubuntu 10.10) in a home network and I want to share a folder on notebook 1 with samba. Notebook 2 should be able to read/write/delete content of the folder.

I installed the packages samba and system-config-samba and I added a user and the share with read/write access to samba with the Samba Configuration GUI.

When I enter

`smb://notebook_1/folder`

in Nautilus on notebook 2 I can enter username and password. But then I can only read the content of the folder. Changing files is not allowed. Can somebody help me?

edit: Here is the part of my smb.conf, where the share is defined:

```
[Images]
    path = /home/user1/Images
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = avahi, user1
```

Do I need to add a semicolon in front of `writeable...`?

Comment: Which user did you use to log in to the Samba share? Did you use the username from the user who created the shared folder on notebook 1?

Comment: No. The user was created in the Samba GUI. So it is not a user of the system, but a samba user. Maybe I should have added that I had to choose a UNIX-username for the new samba user. I chose "avahi". Don't know if this is correct or not...?

Comment: Rather than using SMB (which is primarily for Windows interoperability) is there any reason why NFS isn't an option?

Comment: I could also use NFS. I just want to have an easy method to share folders in a home network.

Comment: For Linux systems (and other unix systems) NFS **is** the easy method.

Comment: With easy I mean: A Windows user with no special knowledge should be able to set it up on Ubuntu... When I look at the official documentation of NFS, this is not easy in that sense. Samba comes closer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to login to the share with a user which has read/write permissions on the system where the folder is shared. Also make sure that that particular user has rights to access the samba share.

If possible, it is always a good idea to go for NFS sharing. As long as you do not need to connect from a Windows box you will be happy with NFS. If you want to continue with NF have a look at the quick start section of this [official Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo).

Comment: The writable flag was not saved for some reason. Now it works with the user-accoutn of notebook1.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the permission to the directory. if your directory sharing path is `/home/user1/Images` then run `chmod 777 /home/user1/Images`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: **Please don't recommend `0777` a.k.a. “please-hack-my-system-and-destroy-my-data” permissions for no apparent reason!** There's almost never a reason to do that because it can be avoided with more sensible modifications like changing (group) ownership. −1